# CppSQLite throwing "LNK2019: unresolved external symbol" error

Tags: c++, sqlite, visual-c++

I'm trying to use CppSQLite wrapper for SQLite. I downloaded and compiled SQLite here: C:\sqlite\sqlite-autoconf-3310100. Then I downloaded CppSQLite to: C:\sqlite\cppsqlite. I then added these folders to include and library directories in MSVS project. Added the sqlite3.lib file to additional dependencies. As far as I'm aware that's all I have to do. I added `#include "CppSQLite3.h"` line. I created declared a CppSQLite3DB variable and MSVS says no problem, it know it comes from cppsqlite header. But when I run the project it throws LNK2019 error. Error code is below.

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849238/how-can-i-resolve-error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol#comment28773509_854480) that is the same problem as mine but I tried all the answers there except the best answer. None of them worked. And I don't understand what to do in the best answer, I can't comment on it since I don't have enough rep, so I had to create a new question. Can anyone explain to me if that answer will work for me aswell? And if so, what am I supposed to do, can you explain me that answer simply? Thanks in advance!

```
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl CppSQLite3DB::CppSQLite3DB(void)" 
(??0CppSQLite3DB@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function "bool __cdecl dbop::connectToDatabaseSQLITE(char 
const *)" (?connectToDatabaseSQLITE@dbop@@YA_NPEBD@Z)
```

Comment: Does CppSQLite3 wrapper has a seperate lib other than sqlite3.lib? If so you should add that lib to your project too not only headers

Comment: Yeah, the dude in that question said something about cppsqlite3.lib but i just couldn't find it. Not [here](https://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=6343&display=Mobile) or [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6343/CppSQLite-C-Wrapper-for-SQLite).

Comment: i am adding as answer

Comment: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/5910058)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/neosmart/CppSQLite/

Get CppSQLite3.h and CppSQLite3.cpp files from here.

Add to your project.

You dont need to make CppSQLite3 seperate lib.

Adding files to project should be enouh

Comment: I added the .h file to Header Files, .cpp file to Source Files. Now when I run it I get 33 unresolved externals, all of them in CppSQLite3.obj. :(

Comment: @OneBadStudent Could you a few of them

Comment: LNK2019 unresolved external symbol sqlite3_close referenced in function "public: void __cdecl CppSQLite3DB::close(void)" (?close@CppSQLite3DB@@QEAAXXZ)

Comment: LNK2019 unresolved external symbol sqlite3_last_insert_rowid referenced in function "public: __int64 __cdecl CppSQLite3DB::lastRowId(void)const " (?lastRowId@CppSQLite3DB@@QEBA_JXZ) bpv2 C:\Users\ASUS\source\repos\bpv2\bpv2\CppSQLite3.obj 1

Comment: sqlite3_last_insert_rowid  this is  in sqlite3.lib library. if you added it than this error should not happen.